# Serial to RS232 for servo control

Tags: arduino, serial-port, servo

I am trying to control an Ultramotion Linear Actuator that takes in strings as commands such as TR TE TA .... etc. I have been able to get the Linear actuator to work using a USB to RS232 converter and the program PuTTY. However i need to control the Actuator with the arduino. I have not been able to get the arduino to control the Actuator so far and i have no clue what the exact problem is that I'm encountering with it. I am using a max2332 circuit breakout board in order to step up the voltage to RS232 levels. I really appreciate any help i receive on this and thank you in advance. Any suggestions as far as trouble shooting the problem or anyone with similar experiences would help greatly. I believe that it would be similar to the following example: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoSoftwareRS232 
However this only takes one character i would need it to take multiple characters (i.e. TA10000) and it also doesn't use the USB to serial connector to take a value which it then echoes out the rx/tx to rs232. it takes a value from an rs232 connector and then outputs back through the rs232 connector. Again any help would be appreciated thank you for your time in advance.
TLDR; 
I need an arduino to take in a string from the USB to serial connector and then output the string using rx/tx to RS232 to a servo

Comment: Arduino does not implement the handshake signals.  Most real serial port devices require them to be turned on.  You can fake them with a soldering iron.  Assuming the device is wired as a DCE, connect DSR to RTS and DTR.

Comment: Did you try using the Arduino USB port and a USB-rs232 converter to connect to the servo?

Comment: That example you link to seems to be a very good fit for your use case. It shows two characters ("hi") transmitted and received using a max2332...?

Comment: There are only 3 pins that are used for the circuit GND, TX, RX @Hans Passant . I wouldnt be able to use the usb-b on the arduino to send signals through the rs232 because i still need it to send signals to the arduino from the computer to the arduino.

Comment: On the device side, not the Arduino side.  Best thing to do is use a telephone.  Ask the device manufacturer first if there's an option to turn handshaking off, next if you can buy a cable, next ask for specific instructions on how to wire the cable so it can talk to an Arduino.

Comment: Which Arduino are you using? Does it have two serial ports or are you using software serial to communicate with the Ultramotion?